# Javascript step by step debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging

Is there a software or a debugger able to highlight all the functions which are executed during the run of a very long script (like a JS script)?

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "JavaScript code coverage"; recommending specific libraries and tools is off-topic for Stack Overflow, however.

Comment: Also in Chrome's dev tools, you can pause at every step of the code's execution, click next, next, next, and see your code running step by step, inspect the variables while time  is frozen, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Chrome Dev Tools.

> ### Open the Coverage tab
>
> 1. [Open the Command Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/command-menu): Press `Control`+`Shift`+`P` or `Command`+`Shift`+`P` (Mac). Or, click Customize And Control DevTools
>    Customize And Controls DevTools and then select `Run` Command.
> 2. Start typing `coverage`, select the Show Coverage command, and then press Enter to run the command. The Coverage tab opens in the Drawer.
>
> [image]
>
> ### Record code coverage
>
> 1. Click one of the following buttons in the Coverage tab
> 2. Click Start Instrumenting Coverage And Reload Page Start Instrumenting Coverage And Reload Page if you want to see what code is
>    needed to load the page.
> 3. Click Instrument Coverage Instrument Coverage if you want to see what code is used after interacting with the page.
> 4. Click Stop Instrumenting Coverage And Show Results Stop Instrumenting Coverage And Show Results when you want to stop
>    recording code coverage.
>
> ### Analyze code coverage
>
> The table in the Coverage tab shows you what resources were analyzed,
> and how much code is used within each resource. Click a row to open
> that resource in the Sources panel and see a line-by-line breakdown of
> used code and unused code.
>
> [image]
>
> - The URL column is the URL of the resource that was analyzed.
> - The Type column says whether the resource contains CSS, JavaScript, or
>   both.
> - The Total Bytes column is the total size of the resource in
>   bytes.
> - The Unused Bytes column is the number of bytes that weren't
>   used.
> - The last, unnamed column is a visualization of the Total
>   Bytes and Unused Bytes columns. The red section of the bar is unused
>   bytes. The green section is used bytes.

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/coverage